# Python Payment details paypal

Tags: python, paypal

Im new with Paypal SDK, I want to get the payment details from the transaction id, my code is below:

```
import libs.paypalrestsdk as Paypals

api = Paypals.configure({
    "mode": "sandbox",
    "client_id": "MY-CLIENT_ID",
    "client_secret": "MY-SECRET"
})

payment = Paypals.Payment.find("5LA50068PM345884U")
```

1. How can execute it?
2. How can pass my client_id and secret to use in the transaction?

Comment: Are you asking how to write and execute Python code? Try the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) in that case. Otherwise you need to clarify what the problem is

Comment: I know how can execute but in the example of paypal is not clarify for me!

Comment: Which part of it is unclear?

Comment: I follow this example of the paypal documentation https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/execute_with_updated_shipping.py but in this example update the payment but I only want to get the transaction information so I only need to execute the payment.find?

Comment: Did you also try their actual `find` [example](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/find.py)? Also it's still rather unclear where your problem is - that question makes it seem as if you didn't even attempt to execute your code.

Comment: I executed and the response is not that i want, the response only show me the headers but any information about the transaction id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132132/discussion-between-victor-and-unholysheep).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the **PayPal Classic API** to get the PayPal transaction details:

```
pip install paypal
```

.

```
from paypal import PayPalInterface

paypal_api = PayPalInterface(
    API_USERNAME    = username,
    API_PASSWORD    = secret,
    API_SIGNATURE   = signatur,
    API_ENVIRONMENT = environment,
    DEBUG_LEVEL=0,
    HTTP_TIMEOUT=30
    )

transaction_details = paypal_api._call(
    'GetTransactionDetails',
    TRANSACTIONID=transaction_id
    )
```

- https://developer.paypal.com/search/?q=GetTransactionDetails
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paypal/

And to answer you questions:

1. You executed it with **Paypals.Payment.find(…)**
2. You don't need to pass it because only have to connect one time with **Paypals.configure(…)**

Comment: Your answer help me a lot but now i want to get the connection status but when i try to print the status of  "ACK" if the connection is success print the value and if is failed not, could you help me?

Comment: Please give example, I never tried to get "connection status". Maybe I was wrong and you don't even connect with  Paypals.configure(…). Maybe you only set infos with this and then send the infos with every "find" call. But you can get the status of an call with transactions.raw["ACK"][0]

Comment: I apologize to not answer you but i solved my problem, now I have troubles cause i want to authorize the payment but always have an transaction id invalid, I used DoAuthorization

Comment: I only search and read payments. Never done something else :-)

Answer (score 1):

pip install paypalrestsdk

```
    import paypalrestsdk
    sdk_mode = 'sandbox'
    paypal_client_id = "paypal_client_id"
    paypal_client_secret = "paypal_client_secret"
    paypal_api = paypalrestsdk.Api({
      'mode': sdk_mode,
      'client_id': paypal_client_id,
      'client_secret': paypal_client_secret})
    payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find("pay-xxx1233", api=paypal_api)
```

Comment: I am try to your answer , but the last line "payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find("pay-xxx1233", api=paypal_api)"   ,I cannot understand value  (find("pay-xxx1233")

Comment: "pay-xxx1233" is PAYMENT ID in find . I was trying to fetch payment detail.